# Append elements to array only if the element does't exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

```
WITH upd AS (
  UPDATE univ.products
  SET source = source::int[] || _source
  WHERE project_id = _project_id AND product_id = _products AND NOT(_source = ANY(source))
  RETURNING id
)

, ins AS (
  INSERT INTO univ.products(project_id, product_id, source, tracked)
  SELECT _project_id, _product_id, ARRAY[_source], _tracked
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM upd) 
  RETURNING id
 )

SELECT id
FROM   upd NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN ins 
INTO   _project_product_id;
```

My situation, I have this function which contains all the above and more, what I am trying to avoid is duplicating the project/products pair, but in the same time update the sources by appending new sources. Now the sources for each product/project pair need to be unique, thats why I've added `NOT(_source = ANY(source))`, but if this is true the `select 1 from up` will not return anything so will try to insert the records into the db to avoid this I've added the below exception.

```
EXCEPTION WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN
    EXIT;
END;
```

This is almost doing what I want, but is not returning any id is there a better way of doing this?

Also I have noticed that if I insert a record, then I insert the same record with a different source(the row id will be 1), and then I insert a different record the row id will be 3 instead of 2;

[EDIT] I've solved my problem by doing:

```
SET source = CASE WHEN NOT(source::int[] @> ARRAY[_source]) THEN source::int[] || _source ELSE source END
```

Is there a better solution? This one seems a bit slow.

Comment: The main of the query seems to be missing, and it's the part that should return results.

Comment: What you really need is a generic version of the intarray `idx` function. I've wanted one often, but the C API for PostgreSQL arrays is horrible so I can never be bothered writing one to submit to core PostgreSQL. I suggest writing a simple SQL function that returns true if an element exists in an array and false otherwise, then using that in your expression.

Comment: @DanielVérité i've updated my question, sorry about that.

Comment: OK. But why trying to cram this complex logic into a single statement? That does not insulate from a race condition between concurrent transactions, if that was the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It's not super efficient, but you can define something like your solution as a function:

```
create or replace function set_append(anyarray, anyelement)
  returns anyarray
  immutable
  PARALLEL safe
  language sql as
$$
  select case when $2=any($1) then $1 else $1 || $2 end;
$$;
```

You can also use that to define an aggregate:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE set_agg( ANYELEMENT ) (
  SFUNC = set_append,
  STYPE = ANYARRAY,
  INITCOND = '{}');
```

This will let you `select set_agg(x order by y)` to control the order of the distinct elements where you can't do `select array_agg(distinct x order by y)`.